# Websphere Liberty Profile JPA 2.1 .and JAXB errors

Tags: websphere-liberty

When I have feature

```
<feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
```

enabled in my server.xml (WLP 8.5.5.7) I get a JAXB context initialization error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Errors getting JAXB context for class
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context


- with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
[err]   at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:116)
[err]   at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:65)
[err]   at com.lca.phoenix.common.util.JsonProcessor.getJaxbContext(JsonProcessor.java:110)
```

When I remove that feature, I don't get the JAXB errors.  I am curious what the connection is between those two seemingly disparate things

I'm on Java 1.8.131 on Win 8.1

Thanks!

Comment: The JPA feature likely parses `persistence.xml` and `orm.xml` by using JAXB internally.  Are you packaging a JAXB implementation in your application that might be conflicting with the one used internally by the JPA feature?

Comment: Brett, I didn' tknow enough to answer your question myself and checked with one of the tech leads here and he says, yes.  So thanks for the insight!